# StreamBuilder returns data while it Query(stream) actually has no data in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, snapshot, stream-builder

I'm using a StreamBuilder with this query:

`FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('driver').where('onlineStatus', isEqualTo: true).where('uid', isEqualTo: _driver.uid).snapshots()`

So, I'm listening to a specefic **driver** if he online(onlineStatus = true) or offline(onlineStatus = false) where uid = _driver.uid (I'm storing the driver uid in Driver object).

This is the code:

```
getSelectedDriver(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: _driversCollection
      .where('onlineStatus', isEqualTo: true)
      .where('uid', isEqualTo: _driver.uid)
      .snapshots(),
    builder: (streamContext, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        print('----- hasData -----');
        return myWidget;
      } else {
        print('----- !!!!!hasData -----');
        return changeTheWidget;
      }
    });
}
```

And in myWidget:

```
myWidget = StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: _requestsCollection.where('uid', isEqualTo: requestId).snapshots(),
              builder: (streamContext, snapshot) {

                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  final requests = snapshot.data.docs;

                  if (requests.isNotEmpty) {
                    var requestStatus = requests[0]['requestStatus'];

                    if (requestStatus == 'Accepted') {
                      print('----- Accepted -----');
                      return SelectedDriverCard(
                        ...
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            waitingForDriver = false;
                          });
                        },
                      );
                    } 
                    else if (requestStatus == 'Refused') {
                      print('----- Refused -----');
                      return SelectedDriverCard(
                            fullName: _driver.fullName,
                            ...
                            onTap: () async {
                              await _requestsCollection.doc(requestId).delete();
                              setState(() {
                                requested = false;
                                requestId = '';
                              });
                            },
                          );
                    } 
                    else {
                      print('----- Waiting -----');
                      return SelectedDriverCard(
                        fullName: _driver.fullName,
                        ...
                        onTap: () async {
                          await _requestsCollection.doc(requestId).delete();
                          setState(() {
                            requested = false;
                            requestId = '';
                          });
                        },
                      );
                    }
                  }
                  return SelectedDriverCard(
                    fullName: _driver.fullName,
                    ...
                    onTap: () async {
                      await _requestsCollection.doc(requestId).delete();
                      setState(() {
                        requested = false;
                      });
                    },
                  );
                } else {
                  print('----------------snapshot.!!!!hasData----------------');
                  return Loading();
                }
              },
            )
```

And in changeTheWidget:

```
changeTheWidget = Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text('It looks like the driver went offline...'),
            Text('Wait until he back online'),
            Loading(),
            Text('Or find another one'),
            GestureDetector(
              child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
              onTap: () async {
                await _requestsCollection.doc(requestId).delete();
                setState(() {
                  requested = false;
                  selectedDriver = false;
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
```

So, how my code works:

1- When I select a **driver** I call the method `getSelectedDriver(context)` (First code above).

2- I'm using this **StreamBuilder** just to keep checking of **driver** in case he went **offline**.

3- So, while he's **online**, I make a **request** to him, and that happens in another **StreamBuilder** in `myWidget` , I'm listening to the **request** I've made to **driver**, so he can **Accept it** or **Refuse it**.

4- If the **driver** goes offline, I return `changeTheWidget`.

Now, everything works fine but when I choose the **driver** then the request StreamBuilder pop up normal, but (with another device) I switch the **Online Status** of the **driver** to **offline** and wait for the Stream to show other **Widget** that tells me the **driver** went offline as you can see in `changeTheWidget`, It doesn't change, the Stream keeps listening to the data and read the data like the **driver** didn't change his status.

I mean the **snapshot** keeps getting in the `if(snapshot.data.docs)` condition but the Query logically it must returns no **data** so it shows the offline message to me.

P.S: Code has no Errors, it works properly.

I hope I made everything clear. If something is not clear, tell me I'll try to explain more.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, it's just by adding another condition to `snapshot.hasData` which is:

```
if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data.docs.isNotEmpty)
```

So, now when the driver goes offline, it changes the screen and tells the user 'the driver went offline.'